# Label polygons in MapInfo like QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, labeling

I was wondering if there is a way to angle Polygon labels in MapInfo like it's done in QGIS (see image link below).

[image]

Comment: Why are Highways Polygons? for Mapinfo Roads should be lines and then you can curve along segments - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs-moPHGqFE&t=2m58s

Comment: This is what was provided to me by the client, I also have a line layer, however this does not contain the road names. I only need the road name labels as I will be adding the highway line layer over and making the road polygons invisible.

Comment: I would convert the polygons to lines (and preserving attributes).

Answer (score 1):

James,
If you have the roads as polylines as well, you could transfer the road name from the polygons to the polylines using Table > Update Column.

You might have to add a new column to the polyline layer before using the Update column feature

```
Update: RoadPolylines
Column: Roadname
Get values from: RoadPolygons
Where Object from RoadPolylines Are Within Object from RoadPolygon
With: Value 
From: Roadname
```

HTH